# Implementación Socket.IO con Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, socket.io, websocket

Qué tal!

Estamos realizando una aplicación web en Angular para unas votaciones. Y se quiere implementar una funcionalidad que es, cuando una moción se vaya a cerrar, poder enviar un mensaje a todos los votantes desde una pantalla de administrador.

La idea es que sea en tiempo real.

Había pensado en usar observables y consumir un servicio cada 1 segundo para validar nueva información en la tabla, sin embargo considero que no es buena practica porque son muchos votantes y se puede colgar el servidor por tanta petición.

Estuve leyendo sobre Socket.IO y creo que me puede servir para lo que quiero hacer. Pero, tengo una duda.

- Entiendo que para Socket.IO se levanta un servidor. Pero, ¿ese
  servidor es el mismo del backend o tendría dos servidores, backend y
  socketio?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que tu pregunta no es de Angular sino Node.

En el mismo servidor puedes tener tus servicios APIS y también Socket.

Nota que en este ejemplo utilizo el puerto 3500; espero te sirva, saludos.

```
let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3500
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const server = express()
    .use(app)
    .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening Socket on ${ PORT }`))

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

//socket
const socketIO = require('socket.io')

global.io = socketIO(server)

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Client connected....');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('Client disconnected'))
})
```